# saber si la diferencia es de 5 min entre dos campos datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo 2 consultas que me regresan movimientos de inventarios, algunos son complementarios, (anaquelacion por compra y ajustes de anaquelacion) cada consulta regresa un valor de datetime

Aqui viene lo que me ha dado problemas... como saber si entre el primer dato datetime y el segundo dato de la consulta han pasado 5 min de diferencia ...

Supongamos

FechaMovimiento 1
2020-02-01 14:20:00.000

FechaMovimiento 2

2020-02-01 14:23:00.000

como verificar esto en automatico... y agregar esto en una tabla temporal, el unico problema es el validar si ha pasado ese tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comprobar tiempo transcurrido dispones de la [función](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) `DATEDIFF`

Esta función tiene 3 parámetros: el tipo de dato a retornar (segundos, minutos, horas, ...), la primera fecha y la segunda fecha a comparar.

Así para saber los minutos transcurridos entre FechaMovimiento1 y FechaMovimiento2 tendremos:

```
declare @Minutos int = DATEDIFF(minute, FechaMovimiento1, FechaMovimiento2)
```

Si los dos campos los tienes en una tabla, podras calcularlo:

```
SELECT FechaMovimiento1, FechaMovimiento2, DATEDIFF(minute, FechaMovimiento1, FechaMovimiento2) as Minutos
FROM Tabla
```

Comment: Y si lo quisiera agregar como condicional ?, seria posible?

Comment: Si, puedes poner un where datediff(minute, FechaMovimiento1, FechaMovimiento2)>5